# Defining the argument of a python function to be n of the same lists

Tags: python

I have a python function itertools.product() and a list `A = [1, 2, 3]`. I would like to find a way to do `itertools.product(A, A, A, ...)` where the number of `A`s in the argument can be determined by a variable n.

I tried `itertools.product([A]*n)`, which obviously did not work. I expected this to not work, but I will reiterate that I would like to code something so that `itertools.product([A]*n)` => `itertools.product(A, A, A, ...)` where there are `n` `A`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use argument unpacking using `*`: `product(*[A]*n)` to stick to your idea, but better use `repeat` option in that case if all `A`'s in your list are to be the same: `product(A, repeat=n)`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number of repetitions with the optional `repeat` keyword argument. For example, `product(A, repeat=4)` means the same as `product(A, A, A, A)`.